# Removeallobjects in array from another view? Xcode iOS

Tags: xcode, arrays

Please forgive me is this is too vague. I have an app that has populated arrays based on where the user browses to. One is just all sites visited and is accessible in another viewcontroller and another is all text input in to the textview which is displayed while the user types. I don't know if any of that is important but my question is, I would like to have a settings page that has the option to clear that data. I can do it from the header file in that view its self but not sure how to send the removeallobjects command to other views or arrays.
In each view I have a button to call this:

```
-(IBAction)clearPreText {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 

                      initWithTitle:@"clear all predictive typing?"
                      message:@"press ok to clear"
                      delegate: self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];

[alert show];



}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {




if (buttonIndex == 1) {




    [pastUrls removeAllObjects];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:autocompleteUrls forKey:@"PastUrls"];

    [self.autocompleteTableView reloadData];



}}
```

I would like to place those buttons in a new view, a settings page.
Thanks for anything.

Answer (score 2):

Both controllers will have access to the app delegate and the app delegate will have access to  each of your controllers.  When I need to do something like this, I usually do it through the app delegate.